# Android Studio no strikeout on deprecated methods/variables

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm migrating to Android Studio IDE. But  deprecated things are not marked with strikeout.

Eclipse marked all deprecated things with strikeout and now it's a little uncomfortable to use Studio.

For example:

I've marked this method as deprecated but nothing happenned.

[image: Deprecated 1]

And the same happens in Android source files:

[image: Deprecated 2]

But when using those methods\variables they are marked appropriately:

[image]

`Deprecated API usage` is checked in Settings:

[image: Deprecated 3]

And also default styles:

[image: Deprecated 4]

Android Studio v2.1.1

Comment: AFAIK, nothing is supposed to happen on the declaration. The strikethrough is shown on uses of the deprecated symbol.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know, thanks. But is there any way to strikethrough deprecated declarations to make them more readable like it was in Eclipse?

Comment: The behavior here Android Studio "inherits" from IntelliJ IDEA. Some light Google searching is not coming up with anything for IDEA, though it may be worthy of more investigation.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I have to get used to Android Studio